# Modernizr and WordPress - How can I add a CSS class to the html element?

Tags: css

The instructions for implementing Modernizr state that I should add `class="no-js"` to the `<html>` element.

Is there a way to do this in WordPress using a hook or filter? If at all possible, I'd prefer to do this without editing the theme files.

Comment: Sorry, I fail at previewing and escaping my code - I need to add the class to the `<html>` element (see edited question). Also, I need to add it via PHP. "no-js" stands for "No Javascript", so using javascript to set that class is not an option.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: This thread is a bit outdated, sorry, but may this plugin be usefull for someone reading you, as i did:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/genesis-js-no-js/faq/?topic_id=22757 Enjoy !

Comment: There is a hook to modify the body classes, you can add it there. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 7):

This is not exactly the answer, but you can use a hook for [`language_attributes`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/language_attributes?version=3.0&file=wp-includes/general-template.php) filter. This action is fired at `<html>` tag and what it does is simply echo the `lang=en` string, for ex. You can hook to that and replace the string with your CSS class, like this:

```
add_filter('language_attributes', 'modernizr');
function modernizr($output) {
    return $output . ' class="no-js"';
}
```

This works only when your theme follows the [WordPress Theme Development Checklist](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Document_Head_.28header.php.29). Sometimes people don't follow this and that breaks the technique.

Comment: I'd considered that, but it looks a little hacktacular, so I'm hoping to find another solution. Will leave the question open to see if there are any other interesting suggestions.

Comment: @Tex Take a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/language_attributes). @rilwis suggestion is best practice. Place his code in your functions.php file.

Comment: @kaiser I'm familiar with that article, but I don't see anything in the article that suggests that using `language_attributes` to set other attributes in the `<html>` tag is 'best practice'. As a matter of fact, the article states that the two acceptable parameters to the function are 'xhtml' and 'html', which supports my contention that this is a bit hacky. Anyway, if it works without detrimental side effects and it's the only way, I'll probably go with it.

Comment: @Tex you can still add your own filter or hook. functions.php always runs before any other file.

Comment: "*Place his code in your functions.php file.*" - Actually, since the OP state that he doesn't want to edit Theme files, I would recommend either **1)** place the code in a **Child Theme** `functions.php` file, or **2)** place the code in a **site-specific Plugin**.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game here, but just to add to @Rilwis answer you could add the script to a function that checks if the `no-js` language attributes are added or not.

While I don't use Modernizr, I do use the no-js detection script from twenty-sixteen so inclusion is pretty much the same. Doing it this way, you don't have to worry about removing the function added to `wp_head` or `wp_enqueue_scripts` since it happens automatically when you remove the filter.

### Adding Removing Filter Approach

```
/** 
 * Javascript Detection Filter
 * 
 * remove_filter( 'language_attributes', 'lang_atts_js_detect' ); 
 */ 
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'lang_atts_js_detect' );
function lang_atts_js_detect($output) {
    return $output . ' class="no-js"';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    if ( has_filter( 'language_attributes', 'lang_atts_js_detect' ) ) {
        echo "<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>\n";
    }
}, 0);
```

---

### Theme Support Approach

Another option could be to do this using `current_theme_supports`.

```
/** 
 * Javascript Detection Theme Support
 * 
 * add_theme_support( 'js-detect' ); 
 */ 
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'js-detect' ) && !is_admin() )
        add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'lang_atts_js_detect_class' );
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'lang_atts_js_detect_script', 0 );
}
function lang_atts_js_detect_class($output) {
    return $output . ' class="no-js"';
}
function lang_atts_js_detect_script() {
    echo "<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>\n";
}
```